# mac crontab open application behaves differently than opening from Dock

Tags: macos, bash, shell, cron

i wrote a shell script that checks if Microsoft Lync is running and Opens the app if not running. if i execute the shell script directly from bash terminal, it opens up Lync and as Remember Username/password is clicked it logs on fine.
the same script i entered in crontab entries to be run every minute so i can start Lync if not running already. But for some reason when the Lync is opened from this crontab script execution, the Lync application does not auto sign-in and asks me for the Lync password. 
why is this behavior different ?

crontab entry -

> * 9-17 * * 1-5 $HOME/lync.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

LYNC_PID=$(launchctl list | grep "Lync" | awk '{print $1}')

if [ "$LYNC_PID" = "" ]
then
echo "Lync not running"

ERROR_REPORTER_PID=$(ps -ef | grep -i "[m]icrosoft error reporting" | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "$ERROR_REPORTER_PID" != "" ]
then
    echo "Killing Microsoft Error Reporter" 
    kill -9 $ERROR_REPORTER_PID
fi
echo "Starting Lync" 
open /Applications/Microsoft\ Lync.app

fi
```

Comment: The `grep "[m]oo" | awk '{ bar }'` anti-pattern can fruitfully be refactored to `awk '/[m]oo/ { bar }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dock and other interactive commands running in a session have access to the session's information, including your keyring and the screen.  Cron has none of this.  Attempting to run interactive programs from `crontab` is doomed to fail, in pesky corner cases if not outright in the regular main usage scenario.

Comment: so there's no way to mimic the User click on dock ?
the Microsoft lync app keeps on crashing, so i wanted to automate identifying that and restarting the app. but due to this crontab's behavior, am unable to do so. any advice ?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht2602 but not from Cron, no.  If you want to restart Lync periodically, wrap your current script in a `while true` loop and add that to your startup items.

Comment: that is a painful fix.

Comment: i made it work by creating a launchd job which executes my script every 10 secs. i modified script to run only during weekdays and during workhours 9-5. i parse date in script and if day and hour falls in the desired range, then only i check whether lync running or not and whether to restart if not running.